# Connection editors OK -button greyed out

Tags: networking, kubuntu, network-manager

How do I press OK, I get this window when adding mobile broadband -connection?

[Picture of this dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNviq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OK button might get active after entering a user name and password.These fields are not grey for a purpose. You could test this behaviour even without knowing the actual valid password.